Old ESTA overwritten by new ESTA?
Let’s say I fly to the US on 9/26/2024 and come back 10/13/2024. My ESTA expires 10/9/2024. As far as I know no troubles as long as I stay in the USA the whole time. But because I may want shortly to cross the border to Canada after 10/9 I am tempted to apply for a new ESTA, also because then I‘d have another big window of 2 years to travel there. So I am thinking of applying for a new ESTA right now.
But now comes the problem: what if my new ESTA gets refused? Does that make my current ESTA invalid, so that all of a sudden I cannot go to the US at all? Because then it would make more sense to wait till I am in the US to apply for a new ESTA. In the worst case I‘d still could make my trip.

Yes, if the new ESTA gets refused, your old one is invalid, because that would mean they consider you ineligible to enter under VWP. However, as far as I understand (do NOT take my word for it - email esta@cbp.dhs.gov and ask), if re-entering from Canada by land (not air) within the 90-day admission period you'd NOT need a new ESTA, since you're not technically requesting a new admission, but rather continuation of your previous one.

The ESTA and the I-94 are two different things. Without a valid ESTA OP probably wouldn’t get a boarding pass and wouldn’t get to see CBP (in pre-clearance) to be readmitted under the existing I-94.

@jcaron Right, only had land border crossings in mind, not air travel. Edited!

Even land border crossings require an ESTA now, but of course there’s no airline to convince. No idea if CBP would grant entry on the existing I-94 without a valid ESTA though.

@jcaron That's why I advised to double-check with CBP, but my understanding is it'd be OK

@jcaron You need either an ESTA, a valid visa, OR a valid I-94(W). An expired ESTA/visa should not be a problem, as the existing I-94(W) will be used via a process Automatic Revalidation.  I would make sure you have a printout of the current I-94 (from https://cbp.gov/i94) and probably only try this if travelling through an airport with US Pre-clearance. Canadian airline staff should know this rule well, as it's commonly used - at least for expired visas.

The official logic behind this is that one of the question is whether you've been refused an ESTA. This is a "yes/no" question.  ESTA's are considered invalid if the answers previously given to any "yes/no" questions change.  So once you've been denied the (new) ESTA, the answer to a yes/no question on your initial application has changed, so that ESTA is no longer valid.

@Doc No, I'd only use this at the land border in fact
